# How to configure pyodbc to use with Databricks when using SQL Server as a driver

Tags: python, sql-server, databricks, pyodbc

Overview: I am running a virtual machine for work. On that machine, I am connecting to our Databricks account. Rather than creating a connection to our data warehouse and repository, I prefer to use the python package pyodbc, to connect to our database and thus its corresponding tables. If I am running jupyter notebook on the VM and connect to our database that way, I can run this in a cell:

```
import pyodbc
pyodbc.drivers()
```

And the output will be a list of available drivers, one of which is 'SQL Server'. This seems to be the only one that I could get to connect to my work's database through my jupyter notebook. So, in attempt to reproduce that environment, but in databricks.

Problem: I have seen other issues where the following code worked to add 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' to the list of drivers, which is good, but again, I can only seem to get SQL Server to work as a driver, when it comes to connecting to my work database.

```
%sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -q -y install msodbcsql17
```

Ideal Solution: Run something similar to the above, but one that installs 'SQL Server' to the list of available drivers for pyodbc.

Current Code being executed:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};" +
                      "SERVER=my_server_name;" +
                      "DATABASE=my_db_name;" +
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
```

Note: even if I switch the driver to ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server, which CAN be loaded/added, it still doesn't work. I prefer SQL Server for the driver, as it worked fine in my jupyter notebook.

Additional Info: I am wondering if when using Databricks, it's as though you are on a virtual machine? Since I am already using a VM, is it that I am technically on a VM within a VM? On my VM, when run that above code to connect to the sql server, it finds it no problem. Perhaps in databricks, it needs more specific information to connect to that SQL Server? A url perhaps?

Comment: when you're using pyodbc, process runs on a single node and you don't have advantages of distributed data processing. You can connect to SQL server using JDBC - driver for SQL Server is bundled with Databricks

Comment: I only use it to connect to the data, so it doesn't need to be fast. This is my preferred method, because I know it does what I want it to.